# WPF : Attaching some data to a Button

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

Problem :

'Im populating a ListView with ControlTemplate.
In this template for each item there will be a button that when clicked need to perform some action.

How i can access the object that generated the ListViewItem so i can fetch something (like a id).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DataContext` is your friend. Each list item (and button inside that item if you haven't override button's `DataContext`) will have a data item which was used to generate the item in `DataContext` property.

Comment: The property is also inherited to child controls. You can access the DataContext property of the button itself.

Answer (score 0):

if you are creating buttons dynamicly , you can use the `Tag` property for attach your data, or inherit the `Button` class as `My_Button` and set a Property wich you need like "userId"

in the other way
try watch the `Parent` property of clicked button.

for example :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
          Button clickedButton = sender as Button;
          ListViewItem holderItem = clickedButton.Parent as ListViewItem;
          Console.WriteLine("You are clicked the buton in " + holderItem.Name);
        }
```

or inline solution:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
              Console.WriteLine("You are clicked the buton in " + ((sender as Button).Parent as ListViewItem).Name);
            }
```